# i have trouble stopping the music

Tags: java, javasound

I am having trouble with the following code; I created 2 classes:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Banger implements DataLine {
    void playMusic(String musicLocation) {
                
        try {
            File musicPath = new File(musicLocation);
            
            if  (musicPath.exists()) {
            AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.stop();
            clip.open(audioInput);
            clip.start();
            clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

in  this class i am trying to create a music player, and it works perfectly.

```
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        message6.setVisible(true);
        options.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        String filepath = "p.wav";
        Banger musicObject = new Banger();
        musicObject.playMusic(filepath);
        }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        message6.setVisible(false);
        options.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        Banger musicObject = new Banger();
        String filepath = "p.wav";
        clip.stop();
    }
```

In this class I try to make a button do things, and it works, and then I try to play music while I'm on the button, and stop it while I'm off - it starts but it won't stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that you are closing in `mouseExited` is a new, individual instance of `Banger`, not the instance that you instantiated.

I recommend the following measures.

(1) Make an instance variable for `Banger` in the class that plays and stops it.
(2) In Banger, separate the constructor from individual methods that start and stop the `Clip`.

Some other recommendations:

- I don't see how you are doing anything that requires `DataLine`, and I would drop the `implements DataLine` from your `Banger` class.
- The `loop` method of `Clip` will start the playback, so you don't need the `start` method.

Quick rewrite of Banger:

```
public class Banger {

    private Clip clip;

    public Banger(String musicLocation) {
            
        try {
            File musicPath = new File(musicLocation);
            if  (musicPath.exists()) {
                AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInput);
            else {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void play() {
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    public void stop() {
        clip.stop();
    }
}
```

And now, `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` should access the same instance variable.

```
private Banger banger; 
public void setBanger(String filepath) {
    banger = new Banger(filepath);
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // some code omitted
    banger.play();
}
// similar for mouseExited, calling banger.stop();
```